# docker compose yaml - command

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a creation of a new database using mysql

this is the snippet I have in my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
mysql:
  image: mysql
  container_name: mysql-machine
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mxdb
    MYSQL_USER: mxdb
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: mxdb
  command: mysqladmin create testing_db
```

Now when i run `docker-compose up`

I watch the console, and it says

```
mysql_1    | mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
mysql_1    | error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
mysql_1    | Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

So how do I re-write the command piece, so i get the service working properly?

I want to create more than one database. So manually using commands is the easiest way.

Comment: Which mysql image are you using ?

Comment: `image: mysql` means it's the official `mysql`, with the tag `latest`. https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should run the mysql container and then have another container do the data import. Example:

*.credentials*

```
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
MYSQL_USER=mxdb
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mxdb
MYSQL_DATABASE=mxdb
```

Run the container:

```
docker run --name mydb -d --env-file .credentials mysql
```

If you want to import data from file, create a new container, link to the one that is already running and do the import:

```
docker run --rm -t --link mydb:DB -v /path/to/dump.sql:/dump.sql mysql bash -c "mysql -h DB -u mxdb -pmxdb mxdb < /dump.sql"
```

If you just want to run a command, use:

```
docker run --rm -t --link mydb:DB mysql mysql -h DB -u mxdb -pmxdb -e "CREATE DATABASE bar"
```

or

```
docker exec -t mydb mysql -u mxdb -pmxdb -e "CREATE DATABASE bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should override the `command` to create the database.

In docker-compose, the `command` should be the command to start the given service in the docker image. In your case, the service is a MySQL server. If you gives a `command` for the mysql service in your docker_compose.yml, the MySQL server will never start.

What you should do is start the `mysql` service, and then run commands in it.

```
mysql:
  image: mysql
  container_name: mysql-machine
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mxdb
    MYSQL_USER: mxdb
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: mxdb
```

Start the service:

```
docker-compose up
```

Connect to it:

```
mysql -umxdb -pmxdb
```

Then create the database:

```
create database testing_db;
```

If you need to automatize this database creation, you could put these SQL commands in a file, and do when needed:

```
cat init_db.sql | mysql -umxdb -pmxdb
```

Comment: This is working solution but if you want to create many databases and use the docker-compose scale, it will not be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this image of mysql: tutum/mysql
You can add the name of the database you want to create at startup as an environment variable:

> environment:
>
> -ON_CREATE_DB="newdatabase"

---

Another solution is to put a shell script on the command part. In the script you start mysql and then create databases and add users:

> command : run.sh

And on you script:

> /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
>
> mysqladmin create testing_db

Comment: This script will not work. First, you'd have to put your script in the Docker image with a custom Dockerfile. Then, as soon as the script ends, the MySQL server will stop (because the `command` finished). And finally, if the database already exists, the creation will crash.

Comment: `ON_CREATE_DB` environment variable on the `tatum/mysql` image is the equivalent of the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable on official mysql image, which OP is already using.